# How to implement a software interrupt?

Tags: c#, algorithm, interrupt

I'm dealing with an C# Windows Forms application. I have some forms and all these forms are sensitive to the value of a global variable. [Static Member Of A Static Class]

I don't want to run a timer on every form and check this variable. I want these forms to be sensitive to the value of this variable and each form to perform its own routine.

What should I do? Is there a standard way to implement these types of algorithms?

Comment: FYI Mohsen ... this has nothing at all to do with "software interrupts"

Comment: *these forms are sensitive to the value of a global variable*. Not sure what you mean by that? Are you looking for [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) ?

Comment: My main skill is Firmware programming , and when I was working with microcontrollers, in many cases we need to define an interrupt and handling them .  I thought we have something similar here .

Comment: Can you be more specific? It doesn't have to be your scenario exactly, but if you could outline an example of what this might look like.

Comment: Imagine that we have several forms and there is a indicator [ light] on each form. We also have a variable that changes. I want the program to be in such a way that if the value of this variable exceeds a certain limit, the light on each of the forms will turn on.

Comment: You are asking for events. Interrupts and events are two entirely different things. Events don't interrupt. They are just part of the application's sequential or synchronous operation execution flow. They are just a commonly executing piece of code. Interrupts on the other hand literally interrupt the application's execution to execute the registered interrupt routines. Software interrupts are usually OS level system interrupts. They interrupt any running application. You can consider system exceptions as a type of software interrupts. Interrupts are always low-level (hardware or OS/kernel).

Comment: [Events (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a normal situation. Sometimes we need to use something like timers. (This is called Polling method). Sometimes we need Interrupts (This is called `Event` in the `C#` terminology).

So. As you said we have an static class:

```
internal static class StaticClass
{
    public delegate void SomethingHappendEventHandler(object sender, EventPayload e);

    public static event SomethingHappendEventHandler SomethingHappendEvent;

    public class EventPayload
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
    
    public static async Task BroadcastAnEvent(string message)
    {
        SomethingHappendEvent?.Invoke(null, new EventPayload()
        {
            Message = message
            // Extra info should be defined in payload class if you want to pass them.
        });
    }
}
```

and we have some `Form`s that wanna catch those `Event`s. for every single form you should do this:

```
    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StaticClass.SomethingHappendEvent += StaticClass_SomethingHappendEvent;
    }

    private void StaticClass_SomethingHappendEvent(object sender, StaticClass.EventPayload e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
```

You can call:

```
 StaticClass.BroadcastAnEvent("My message");
```

Wherever you want and all of these forms will catch this message and they are able to use it.

Comment: Interrupts and events are two entirely different things. Events don't interrupt. They are just part of the application's sequential or synchronous operation execution flow. Interrupts on the other hand literally interrupt the application's execution to execute the registered interrupt routines. Software interrupts are usually OS level system interrupts. They interrupt any running application.

Comment: I'm trying to make it easier to understand for the guy who asked the question based on the things he is trying to say. We don't have `Interrupts` in C# and neither `Polling method`. these are `Concepts`. Low level patterns to deal with such a problems (In operating systems, CPU and ... ). I usually explain whole things when I think its needed.

Answer (score 0):

In high level languages you don't have interrupts, but you have events. Not that the two are the same, (of course you know that an interrupt is generated at the hardware level and are not specifically tied to your application. Events instead don't happen if your code don't do something to trigger them) but in certain way they are similar for the effects that you can trigger on your code.

So, imagine to have a class (even static ones), that let anyone interested in some kind of event happening in that class, to be notified when this event happens.
The event can be anything but usually is something related to a change of state of that class so, changing the value of a *property* is a event that can be notified to anyone interested.

Lets build a class that is able to notify external clients (your forms) that a property (not a simple field) has been changed.

```
public static class MyGlobalData
{
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Private internal value for flag1
    private static bool _myStatusFlag1

    // Public property that every client use to set or read the Flag1
    public static bool StatusFlag1
    {
        get { return _myStatusFlag1; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _myStatusFlag1)
            {
                _myStatusFlag1 = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("StatusFlag1");
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Notify every client interested about the event just happened
    private static void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

So, this static class contains all your static variables (note, they are not just a bunch of public variables but a set of properties with they respective get and set accessors.

At this point, in every form interested to know when the StatusFlag1 changes its value you need to add this code

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
   {
        // This is the key part. Add your listener method
        // so when something changes on MyGlobalData it will
        // be called.
        MyGlobalData.PropertyChanged += ListenerOnForm1;
   }

    private void ListenerOnForm1(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // This is the property name (StatusFlag1)
        Console.WriteLine(args.PropertyName);

        // Now get the name of every static property in the class
        var piInfo =  typeof(MyGlobalData)
              .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static);

        // Find the property with the specific name received
        var p = piInfo.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == args.PropertyName);

        // Do whatever you need to do with the property value
        if(p != null)
            Console.WriteLine(p.GetValue(null));
    }
}
```

The code above is generic so it could be used for many properties, but, of course if you have only one or two properties to check then you can simplify a lot the above code with a simple test like

```
if(args.PropertyName == "StatusFlag1")
    if(MyGlobalData.StatusFlag1 == true)
        .... do whatever you need with it
```

Also, I use the standard [PropertyChangedEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs?view=net-7.0) to transmit just the name of the property, but none stops you from creating a different xxxxxxEventArgs class that could contain whatever information you need to pass along from the MyGlobalData static class.

Comment: This looks great, I'll have to focus on it and check it out more and more, thanks for your time.